# Kubuntu will keep asking for wifi password (Kubuntu 20.04.3)

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, internet, lan

I've been trying to connect to the internet through wifi. I click the network, put in the password and see "configuring interface". Then, a window pops, asking for the password. I put it in (double checked, just in case), and see "configuring interface" again. And the loop repeats. I'm currently accessing the internet through my phone, which makes everything **horribly** slow.

Any ideas why that might be?

Here is some info:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:06f0]
        DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4070]

$ lsusb        
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1058:2623 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements SE 2623
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 079b:0062 Sagem XG-76NA 802.11bg
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1043:8773 iCreate Technologies Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 0e8d:2005 MediaTek Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:5760 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Network info (according to `lshw -C network`)
"`*-usb:1`" below is a USB antenna, maybe I can get mi wifi back using it (if I can figure that out)

```
*-usb:1                   
       description: Wireless interface
       product: 802.11b/g USB WLAN
       vendor: ZyDAS
       physical id: 7
       bus info: usb@1:7
       logical name: wlx0060b348a3ae
       version: 48.10
       serial: 00:60:b3:48:a3:ae
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=zd1211rw driverversion=5.11.0-43-generic firmware=4725 link=no maxpower=500mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=IEEE 802.11
  *-network:0
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 94:e7:0b:c3:8b:47
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-43-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.u latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:a2334000-a2337fff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (11) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno2
       version: 00
       serial: a4:bb:6d:c4:dc:10
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-43-generic firmware=0.4-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:150 memory:a2300000-a231ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:12.3
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 00:60:b3:48:a3:ae
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.11.0-43-generic firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.39 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Also, something in `dmesg` said:

```
[11098.024684] wlx0060b348a3ae: deauthenticated from (my wifi MAC) (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
```

My internal internet card is an intel, and the (potentially broken) usb antenna is an ancient SAGEM/ZyDAS IEEE 802.11 b/g.
With all this info, I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: What does your phone have to do with this? Is your Wi-Fi network hosted by your phones cellular connection? When you enter the password, are you connected at all, or are you just being prompted for the password again? Because if you're never getting connected then either your password is wrong or you are using the wrong settings for your Wi-Fi network.

Comment: Is Wi-Fi accessible on other devices, or are they having the same problem? If the latter is true, reboot the router once and let us know.

Comment: @SakiOsive No, all other computers are connecting fine. Even if they weren't, I can't reboot the router.

Comment: Are you connecting via WPA2, WPA3, or something else? VPN? Try booting to a Ubuntu Live 21.10 USB and see if you have any luck. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.